# Open payment popups in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview, payment-gateway

I have a flutter application that uses the `webview_flutter` package to showcase my website. The website has Moneris payment gateway integrated which makes use of Google Pay. In a browser, when a user clicks on the google pay button, it opens a window popup for the user to select card information to send to Moneris. The payment gateway also is embedded on the webapp as an iframe.

But in the case of the webview, when the user clicks on the google pay button, it opens the google pay URL in the browser. The issue is that after the user selects the card, the card information needs to be returned to Moneris, but since the Google Pay URL is open in the browser, there's no way to send the data back to Moneris iframe in the webapp.

One working solution I could think of is to open the gateway page of my website outside the webview in a in-app-browser instance to complete the checkout. But this feels bad UX.

What are some other possible solutions for this? Apart from implementing a native payment gateway implementation in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most payment gateways restrict payments in embedded browsers (like a WebView). Probably even implementing it on the native WebView won't help. We faced a similar issue recently with Cashfree PG and the only working solution was to implement their flutter/Android SDK. You may then get the callback from their SDK (or your backend) and go forward with the implementation.